# Remove "default" when importing JSON file in Vite+React using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, vite

Whenever I try to import a JSON file, what happens is that it wraps the JSON inside a "default" object, and if you try to call the object, the following error pops-up:
`Property 'default' does not exist on type...`

I have already set `resolveJsonModule` to be `true`.

**language.json**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Afrikaans",
    "country": "za",
    "name": "af",
  }
  ....
]
```

**App.tsx**

```
import * as languages from "./languages.json";

function App() {
  return <div className="App">{JSON.stringify(languages)}</div>;
}

export default App;
```

*What should appear:*

```
[
  {
    "name": "Afrikaans",
    "country": "za",
    "name": "af",
  }
  ....
]
```

*What appears instead:*

```
{
  "default":
    [
      {
        "name": "Afrikaans",
        "country": "za",
        "name": "af",
      }
      ....
    ]
}
```

Here is a link to view the problem: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/condescending-pike-6wkdh4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the JSON data an as array directly, you need to modify the import like this:

```js
import languages from "./languages.json";
```

Then you will be able to access the JSON data directly as an array without the default export:

```js
function App() {
  return <div className="App">{JSON.stringify(languages)}</div>;
}
```

[Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/beautiful-paper-cv5o4u?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx)

Comment: Thank you! It was much simpler than I thought.